# I want to read first line value and subtract it from second line value and go on till end

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am looking for shell script which help me to read data from txt file like below:.

```
name 1
info 21
city 28
pin  31
state 34
   -   39
```

so i need o/p to read second column and write difference between them.

like:

```
20
7
3
3
5
```

and append column name after that So o/P will be like:( ",l-" is constant for all row)

```
20,l-name
7,l-info
3,l-city
3,l-pin
5,l-state
```

I have done code like

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                            


cat ip.txt | awk '{ print $3 }' > op.txt                                                                                                                                             
count= wc -l < op.txt                                                                                                                                                                
echo $count                                                                                                                                                                          
a=1                                                                                                                                                                                  
b=2                                                                                                                                                                                  
while read name                                                                                                                                                                      
do                                                                                                                                                                                   
if [$count -gt $a]  then                                                                                                                                                             
m=sed -n '$a' op.txt                                                                                                                                                                 
n=sed -n '$b' op.txt                                                                                                                                                                 
c=$n-$m                                                                                                                                                                              
echo $c                                                                                                                                                                              
$a=$a+1                                                                                                                                                                              
$b=$b+1                                                                                                                                                                              
fi                                                                                                                                                                                   
done<op.txt
```

--
where i trying to find difference between two value.

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I suggest to use awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly helpful to give us an example that "closely look[s]" like your actual data rather than a sample that accurately represents your data, but to produce the demonstrated output from the given input you could do:

```
awk 'NR>1{ printf "%d,l-%s\n", $2 - val, label } {label=$1; val=$2}' input
```

Comment: Thank you i am getting op like
1,
21,l-name 
24,l-info
28,l-city  ---- but i need out as difference between two value like:
20,l-name
3,l-info
4,l-info

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`, some standard unix tools, plus [`numinterval`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/), and assuming the input is tab delimited with no leading spaces:

```
paste <(cut -f2 ip.txt | numinterval) \
      <(cut -f1 ip.txt | head -n -1 ) | sed 's/\t/,1-/'
```

Output:

```
20,1-name
7,1-info
3,1-city
3,1-pin
5,1-state
```

Comment: #i/bsh/sh 
cat ip.txt | awk '{ print $2 }' > op.txt
count= wc -l < op.txt 
echo $count 
a=1;
h=$(head -n $a op.txt)
echo $h 

#while [$a -lt $count] do 
#echo $a
#true $((a++))
#done 

paste <(cut f2 ip.txt | numinterval)<(cut -f1 ip.txt | head -n -1 )|\sed 's/\t/,l-/'
-------- error -------------work.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('                                                                                                                            
work.sh: line 14: `paste <(cut f2 ip.txt | numinterval)<(cut -f1 ip.txt | head -n -1 )|\sed 's/\t/,l-/''

Comment: @user3668036, For this answer, try `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`.

Comment: tried awk 'NR>1{printf"%d,l-%s\n",$2-val,lable}{lable=$1;val$2}' ip.txt with /bash but  error:   syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @user3668036, There no `awk` code in my answer.  Questions about `awk` code should be posted somewhere else.